# How to disable autocomplete in <h:inputText>?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, autocomplete

I'm making my term paper using JSF 2.0, Java 6 and Tomcat 7, but I'm having some doubts in the development.

In my project I have a `<h:inputText>` tag

```
<h:inputText value="#{turmaMBean.nome}">
    <f:ajax event="keyup" render=":meuForm:minhaTabela" />
</h:inputText>
```

I want to disable autocomplete. I already tried:

```
<h:inputText value="#{turmaMBean.nome}" autocomplete="false">
    <f:ajax event="keyup" render=":meuForm:minhaTabela" />
</h:inputText>
```

However, it didn't work. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: What version of JSF 2.x are you using?

Comment: JSF 2.0, @BuhakeSindi. I said this in the question: `I'm making my term paper using JSF 2.0`

Comment: Sorry, never mind my response then.

Comment: Interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14401137/2459449

Comment: Which scope is your `turmaMBean`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the answer. I searched a lot about this issue and I discover this isn't an issue. When I try to do the following:

```
<h:inputText value="#{turmaMBean.nome}" autocomplete="off">
        <f:ajax event="keyup" render=":meuForm:minhaTabela" />
</h:inputText>
```

I didn't restart my Tomcat Server, and by some strange way Tomcat doesn't updated my view properly. When I tried to restart the server, this attribute start work.

**So, if you need to turn the autocomplete off, use:**

```
autocomplete="off"
```

This probably will work - don't forget to restart  the server, sometimes Tomcat like play with us :p.